# Sharepoint Search - Query FileDirRef

Tags: search, search-results

I want to filter on the search result web part (Sharepoint 2013) by the containing folder on the list, could you please tell me how. thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `path` property.

For example `path:http://site/lists/list/folder`

Comment: i just try it and it don't show any results

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the query builder window?

Comment: this is the query that i'm using :

`{SearchBoxQuery} managedProp1=value  Path:{\SiteCollection.URL}/web/Lists/ListName/Folder (ContentTypeId:xyz*)`

if i remove the folderName it waorks showing me all the list content but if i add it i got 0 result